# Call FFmpeg via JavaCPP：Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat$AVFormatContext

Tags: java, ffmpeg

In CentOS, use javacpp call FFmpeg to do video cropping a frame, in my own development machine using this code is no problem, but in centos6 reported NoClassDefFound: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat$AVFormatContext
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:383) ~[javacv-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:377) ~[javacv-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at cn.xxtui.support.upload.BasicUpload.convertImage(BasicUpload.java:211) ~[classes/:?]
    at cn.xxtui.support.upload.BasicUpload.upload(BasicUpload.java:197) ~[classes/:?]
    at cn.com.ql.wiseBeijing.upload.UploadImage.upload(UploadImage.java:144) ~[classes/:?]
    at cn.com.ql.wiseBeijing.upload.UploadImage.imageCategory(UploadImage.java:51) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180) ~[cxf-core-3.1.12.jar:3.1.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.1.12.jar:3.1.12]
    ... 37 more
```

This is my pom configuration：

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.hoary.ffmpeg</groupId>
    <artifactId>FFmpeg-linux-x86_64</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.1
    </version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
    <artifactId>ffmpeg</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1-1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my code：

```
public String convertImage(String filePath, String imagePath) throws IOException, FrameGrabber.Exception {
    FFmpegFrameGrabber g = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(filePath);
    g.start();
    Java2DFrameConverter java2DFrameConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = java2DFrameConverter.convert(g.grabImage());
    String path = imagePath + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File(path));
    g.stop();
    return path;
}
```

Comment: In centos system, jdk1.7............In my local computer running successfully, but in centos reported this error, I have been looking for a few days of the solution, still can not find.

Comment: Please format your post and add a description what exactly you are trying to do. Just dumping a stack trace here will not get you much help.

Comment: I want to cut a frame from the video file in centos6

Comment: Considering "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat$AVFormatContext" ... are you sure you included everything required? Maybe another library needs to be installed that is on your computer but not the centos one.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem has been solved, due to the lack of a package "javacv-platform".

Comment: Well, then I'll just go ahead and "steal" the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all libraries installed on your computer that are needed.
In this case, "javacv-platform".

This is what gives the hint to think in that direction:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat$AVFormatContext
```

"NoClassDefFound" almost always means that something required is missing.